# Create two separate text files after calculating the items and frequency for a given large data set

Tags: python, text-files, frequency, items

I have a large data set of values which I sorted in descending order and calculated the items and the frequency with a Python code of such large list. The output is in a comma separated list but I want the output to be in a column and saved in two different text files, one text file for the items in one vertical column and the other text file for the frequency of such items in a vertical column. This is my code with which I calculated the items and frequency, I only need suggestions to add the creation of the two separate text files for each parameter in a vertical column.

```
K = [0.11729534, 0.16569225, 0.2672644, 0.19168988, 0.095590018, 0.082994543, 0.087023214, 0.10699161, 0.063435465, 0.028770683, 0.029708872, 0.041429114, 0.046457175, 0.057534702, 0.045394801, 0.051440958, 0.05362796, 0.072624497, 0.099292949, 0.22106786, 0.30126628]

# K values in descending order
K_sorted = sorted(K, reverse=True)


# Calculate frequency for the K values in descending order
items, freqs = np.unique(K_sorted, return_counts=True)
items, freqs = items[::-1], freqs[::-1]
print('New K list without repetitions= ',items)
print('Frequency= ',freqs)
```

Any suggestions
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
with open('k-values.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in items:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)

with open('freq.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
    for listitem in freqs:
        filehandle.write('%s\n' % listitem)
```